# regex and javascript, number with point and zeros

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this function to convert numbers like "1234" to "1.234":

```js
function numberWithPoint(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
}


console.log(numberWithPoint(1234));
console.log(numberWithPoint(1200));
```

but when I have a number like "1200" it converts to "1.2". Why?

Comment: is 1.200 your expected output? where are you seeing 1.2? rather than 1.200 ?

Comment: That function outputs the string "1.200" when you do `numberWithPoint(1200)`. It's working fine.

Comment: I don't get it, it works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/Lfgz9108/3/  but in my appp doesn't works

Comment: Arghhh... I'm creating a json by concatenating some values, I that's the error of this...

Answer (score 4):

Because they are numbers and numbers do not need show extra zeros when converted to a string.

But you can do this:

```js
function numberWithPoint(x) {
  return (x/1000).toFixed(3);
}


console.log(numberWithPoint(1234));
console.log(numberWithPoint(1230));
console.log(numberWithPoint(1200));
console.log(numberWithPoint(1000));
```

The function [`Number.prototype.toFixed`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/number/tofixed) allows you to specify the number of digits to include after the `.`.

Comment: Hmm, I don't get it. In my code doesn't works, it still showing 1.2. In a simple jsfiddle it works fine my code and yours: https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/Lfgz9108/3/

Comment: The output of your fiddle works fine. If your code isn't working on your machine can you send the exact code that is failing?